# QGraphicsRectItem move QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyqt

this code http://pastebin.com/XGWDyRd1

draw a rectangle on the scene. 
when I move it, it does not move the cursor, and jumping somewhere. 
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

typo

```
class MyRect(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print 'press event'    
        super(MyRect, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print 'press release'  
        super(MyRect, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```